# Iterating Through Cells in a Powershell [MATH] Function

Tags: csv, powershell, math, standard-deviation

I'm trying to calculate some basic statistics in PowerShell using [MATH], specifically the Standard Deviation of a group of values in a field named 'td'.

My code currently outputs a number that is much too high to be the standard deviation. For example, in a case where the values in the column have no range (all values were 15), where the Standard Deviation should be zero, the returned value was equal to 15.

which I think may have something to do with incorrect use of `$Y` in this section of code:

```
Foreach ($Y in $STDEVInputFile) {
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($STDEVInputFile[$Y].td - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)
```

However, I'm not familiar enough with PowerShell to be sure. Would anyone out there be able to show me where I'm going wrong? Here is the full code:

```
##################################################
#Calculate statistics for TD column in each file

$i = 1

While ($i -le 211) {

#Set the variable to the filename with the iteration number
$filename = "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\fixed20dSum550Output$i.csv"


#Check to see if that a file with $filename exists. If not, skip to the next iteration of $i. If so, run the code to collect the statistics for each variable and output them each to a different file
If (Test-Path $filename) {

#Calculate the Standard Deviation
#First get the average of the values in the column
$STDEVInputFile = Import-CSV $filename

#Find the average and count for column 'td'
$STDEVAVG = $STDEVInputFile | Measure-Object td -Average | Select Count, Average
$DevMath = 0

$Y = 

# Sum the squares of the differences between each value in the field and the mean 
Foreach ($Y in $STDEVInputFile) {
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($STDEVInputFile[$Y].td - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)

#Divide by the number of samples minus one
$STDEV = [Math]::sqrt($DevMath / ($STDEVAVG.Count-1))

}

#Calculate the basic statistics for column 'td' with the MEASURE-OBJECT cmdlet
$STATS = Import-CSV $Filename |
Measure-Object td -ave -max -min |

#Export the statistics as a CSV
Export-CSV -notype "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\tempstats$i.csv"

#Store the values that will go into the final table as variables
$GetColumns = Import-CSV $filename
$VZA = $GetColumns[0].VZA
$VAZ = $GetColumns[0].VAZ


#Import the temporary stats file, append columns and populate them with the declared variables

Import-Csv "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\tempstats$i.csv" |
  Select-Object @{Name="VZA";Expression={$VZA}},
                @{Name="VAZ";Expression={$VAZ}},
                @{Name="STDDEV";Expression={$STDEV}},
                Count, Average, Maximum, Minimum, Property |


#Export the $STATS file containing everything you need in the correct folder


Export-CSV -notype "c:\zMFM\z550Output\20dSummer\Statistics_TD_20dSum550_$i.csv"

}
$i++
}
```

Comment: Could we have some sample input and expected output? I know PowerShell and like math but haven't done standard deviation in years.

Comment: Are you just using the basic example for your formula from wikipedia? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Standard_deviation#Basic_examples. I also just read how standard deviation works and I think I understand your problem now.

Comment: I wasn't using the example from Wikipedia, no, I use RMSE all the time and just know off the top of my head how it's calculated. I will grab some data momentarily - how do I insert tabular data on SO?

Comment: I suspect you want `$DevMath += [math]::pow(($STDEVInputFile[$Y].td - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)` to say `$DevMath += [math]::pow(($Y.td - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)` (and get rid of the `$Y=` empty line before the foreach loop). The `$stdevinputfile[$y]` incorrect lookup is going to return null/0, so for your example of all 15s in the input, instead of each step doing 15-15=0 squared, you are doing 0-15 = -15 squared

Comment: Okay, here is an example of my output, where the input is a column consisting solely of values equal to 0.025. Hence, the Standard Deviation should be zero, but instead it's equal to the value of 0.025. 
VZA VAZ STDDEV Count Average Maximum Minimum
10 60 0.0250139 900 0.025 0.025 0.025

Comment: Paste that data into the question. As long as it is spaced properly we can make it look good.

Comment: Should also move this line out of the loop. Does not need to be there: `$STDEV = [Math]::sqrt($DevMath / ($STDEVAVG.Count-1))`

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler That is the start of the answer if you are not already doing it. I noticed that when I ran the code and got all zeros for the response.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler Aha, thank you for that, I figured I was doing something wrong with `$Y`. Also @Matt I've taken your advice and moved that line of code out of the loop. It appears to be properly calculating the Standard Deviation now. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think:

```
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($STDEVInputFile[$Y].td - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)
```

should be

```
$DevMath += [math]::pow(($Y.td - $STDEVAVG.Average), 2)
```

The original `$STDEVInputFile[$Y].td` part is going to return null/0, so for your example of all 15s in the input, instead of each step doing 15-15=0 squared, you are doing 0-15 = -15 squared.

---

You may also want to get rid of the $Y= empty line before the foreach loop, as it is(maybe) setting $Y to the output of the whole loop, and if nothing else using that while using $Y inside the loop is confusing.